# Pegar conteúdo dentro de várias divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Precisa pegar o conteúdo de várias div's com classes iguais. Por exemplo:

```
<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 1</li>
</div>

<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 2</li>
</div>

<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 3</li>
</div>
```

Quero pegar tudo que tiver dentro das classes `minhaDiv` e exibir em outra div, de forma que fique assim:

```
<div class='minhaDiv'>
 <li>Conteudo 1</li>
 <li>Conteudo 2</li>
 <li>Conteudo 3</li>
</div>
```

Já fiz com jquery `.text()` e de fato funciona, mas preciso que as tags `<li>` sejam "pegas" também. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Uma dúvida, a div com classe `minhaDiv` já vai estar criada e é preciso apenas adicionar o conteúdo dos elementos `<li>` ou a `<div>` vai ser criada junto com o JavaScript?

Comment: Você leu sobre li e ul que postei?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer...uma delas é:

Primeiro você concatena todo o conteúdo das divs de classe `conteudo` e coloca todos os htmls dentro de um `array`.

Depois coloca todo o conteúdo do `array` na sua div `resultado`.

```js
var conteudoArr = [];

$(".conteudo").each(function () {
  conteudoArr.push($(this).html());
  });

$(".resultado").html(conteudoArr.join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 1</li>
</div>

<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 2</li>
</div>

<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 3</li>
</div>

Div Resultado \/
<div class='resultado'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de `.text()`, use `.html()` junto com `.each`, assim:

```js
$(function() {
     $("#testar").click(function() {
         var htmlStr = "";
       
         $(".conteudo").each(function() {
             htmlStr += $(this).html();
         });
       
         $(".minhaDiv").html(htmlStr);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 1</li>
</div>

<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 2</li>
</div>

<div class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 3</li>
</div>

<hr>

<button id="testar">Clique aqui para testar</button>

<div class="minhaDiv"></div>
```

Note uma coisa importante, as tags LI não deve ser usada dentro de outros elementos, os elementos que elas devem ser usadas são `<OL>` e `<UL>`, então pode mudar para isto:

```js
$(function() {
     $("#testar").click(function() {
         var htmlStr = "";
       
         $(".conteudo").each(function() {
             htmlStr += $(this).html();
         });
       
         $(".minhaDiv").html(htmlStr);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 1</li>
</ul>

<ul class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class='conteudo'>
 <li>Conteúdo 3</li>
</ul>

<hr>

<button id="testar">Clique aqui para testar</button>

<ul class="minhaDiv"></ul>
```

As margens e espaços remova com CSS

Comment: respondemos no mesmo segundo com a mesma ideia e implementações "diferentes".. rs `+1`

Comment: @MarllonNasser deixei um up pra ti também

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se é correto usar um item de uma lista sem uma lista.

No puro Javascript fica assim:

```html
<body onload="getbyclass()">
    <ul class='conteudo'>
        <li>Conteúdo 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='conteudo'>
        <li>Conteúdo 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='conteudo'>
        <li>Conteúdo 3</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div id='test'>Resultado</div>
</body>
<script>
function getbyclass()
{
 var content = document.getElementsByClassName('conteudo'),
     minhaLi = document.createElement("li"),
     minhaUl,
     contlenght = content.length;
     minhaUl = "<ul>";
     for(var i = 0; i < contlenght; i++)
     {
         minhaUl += "<li>" + content[i].innerText + "</li>";
     } 
     minhaUl += "</ul>";
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = minhaUl; 
}
</script>
```